# Sending webservice XML response through Websphere with WS Security. What would add a namespace prefix to my XML?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, websphere

I have a webservice that receives a request and sends an xml response. Something was adding a namespace prefix "a" to all of my elements. Then recently we had a server restart and suddenly the namespace prefix is gone. No one knows why it was there in the first place or why it is gone now. Any suggestions? We got everything working by removing the code that handled the namespace prefix in the past. We're just curious at this point why was it there and what caused it to go away. There were no changes to the client code.

Seen on servers with JVMs version Java 6 and 7

Websphere version 8.5

**XML Logged by Webservice**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <MainElement xmlns="somenamespace">
            <elementone>
                <elementtwo/>
            </elementone>
        </MainElement>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**XML Received by requesting service**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
                  <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:removed</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:Action>http://somewebsite.com/service</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:removed</wsa:RelatesTo>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <a:MainElement xmlns:a="somenamespace">
            <a:elementone>
                <a:elementtwo/>
            </a:elementone>
        </a:MainElement>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Something was adding a namespace "a" to all of my elements`?

Comment: See the code block above. When this xml leaves my webservice it does not have a namespace in the body section. When it reached the requester it has a namespace. We have no idea what was adding it. Code was added to handle the namespace, but now it is gone again. Where did it come from and where did it go? Haven't had any luck answering these questions.

Comment: What is the xml that is served by the server? That will help to compare and understand the problem.

Comment: What XML are you requesting? The XML request sent to the webservice or the XML Response as it is produced and logged by my webservice?

    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
     <soapenv:Body>
      <MainElement xmlns="http://ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2">
       <elementone>
        <elementtwo/>
       </elementone>
      </MainElement>
     </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: Then what you added in the comment(it is using default namespace) and the question are same.

Comment: You're saying the "a" is a default namespace? What adds that? Why would it suddenly stop being added?

Comment: No, it was clearly mentioned that the xml present in your comment is using default namespace(xmlns="ACORD.org/Standards/Life/2") and the one from your question is using namespace prefix which is `a:`. But in both cases have the namespace. So, you should not really worry any, IMO.

Comment: Got it, so my question is perhaps is wrong. Why/When/Where does the prefix get added onto the XML?

Comment: Different tools uses different conventions some default namespace and some with prefix etc.